# Enable/Disable button that changes when clicked and executes SQL

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

So basically I am using PHP/AJAX/JavaScript/SQL, and I'm new to it all, to display a list of all my users with a button beside each on that says 'Enable' if there is a 1 in my 'Enabled' column in the database or 'Disable' if there is a 0. The button beside each user displays properly when I first load the page, and if the user has an 'Enable' button, it does enable the user when I click on it, the text changes to 'Disable' but it doesn't disable the user when clicked.

If the user has a 'Disable' button when the page is first loaded, clicking it will change it to blank and the user is not disabled.

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I'll include my code so far below.

**Code for enable/disable button in adminPage.php**

```
if($enabled=='1'){
            $allUsers.='<button id="adminButton_'.$username.'" onclick="adminHandler(\'disable\',\''.$username.'\',\'adminButton_'.$username.'\')">disable</button>';

            }
            else if($enabled=='0')
            {
              $allUsers.='<button id="adminButton_'.$username.'" onclick="adminHandler(\'enable\',\''.$username.'\',\'adminButton_'.$username.'\')">enable</button>';

            }
```

**adminHandler function in adminPage**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

function adminHandler(action,username,elem){
    var conf = confirm("Press OK to '"+action+"' this user.");
    if(conf != true){
        return false;
    }
    _(elem).innerHTML = "processing ...";
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "Includes/adminProcessing.php");

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            if(ajax.responseText == "enable_ok"){
                _(elem).innerHTML = "Disable";
            } else if(ajax.responseText == "disable_ok"){
                _(elem).innerHTML = "Enable";
            } else {
                _(elem).innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send("action="+action+"&username="+username);
}
```

**The adminProcessing.php page**

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && isset($_POST['username']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];


        if($_POST['action'] == "enable")
        {

            $sql = "UPDATE users SET enabled='1' WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";


            $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            mysqli_close($conn);
            echo "enable_ok";
            exit();
        }

        else if($_POST['action'] == "disabled"){
              $sql = "UPDATE users SET enabled='0' WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";


            $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            mysqli_close($conn);
            echo "disable_ok";
            exit();
        }
```

**AJAX File**

```
function ajaxObj(meth, url) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(meth, url, true);
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x) {
    if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem may be at `else if($_POST['action'] == "disabled"){`

Comment: Haha, duh, thanks for that. Now I just need to have it so that when the button is clicked it can be used again without having to reload the whole page.

Comment: You should also update the onclick code. Or you could use other method to store the action, like dataset: Use a `data-action` attribute on the buttons and update it after the ajax call. Of course, read the attribute instead of the `action` parameter in `adminHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

Your "adminHandler" is being passed "disable", but you're checking for "disabled."